# Given $b$ and given $c$, how do you solve for $A$, in $Ab = c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This might be silly, but let us say that I have a matrix $A$, (a rotation matrix actually), where $A = \begin{bmatrix} cos\theta & -sin\theta \\ sin\theta & cos\theta \end{bmatrix} $. I am given $b = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$, and $c = \begin{bmatrix} -4.95 \\ -0.705 \end{bmatrix}$

I am somewhat stumped as to how to approach this... this is different than being given $A$ and $c$, and solving for $b$. Anyway, I can solve it geometrically, but how may I solve it algebraically? Thanks.

Comment: Expand $A{\bf b}={\bf c}$ to give two scalar equations: you should be able to solve these to find $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.

Comment: @David I should add that this is exactly what I did, and this was easy for 2 dimensions, but what if the problem was much larger?

Comment: Gaussian elimination works well in such cases.

Comment: @Ayesha Not sure how GE would work in this case, as I am solving for $A$ itself...

Comment: Ok theres just one canonical rotation matrix in a 2D plane, there are however way more in higher spaces.
So if you solve this in let's say 3D you need more vectors.
But as Ayesha pointed out just substitute $\alpha = \cos\theta. \beta=\sin\theta$ do gaussian elimination, and then calculate the arcs from that

Comment: Do you mean e.g. a $3\times3$ case?  I *think* I can probably answer this.  Not sure I want to try $4\times4$ or bigger ;-)

Comment: Do I get it right that you have given $b$ and $c$ and want to find an $A$ such that $Ab=c$? Any such $A$ can be written as $A=cb^T/(b^Tb)+Z(I-bb^T/(b^Tb))$.  Does $A$ have to be a rotation? There's also an explicit formula for a Householder reflection mapping $b$ to $c$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Yes! That's exactly my problem. I have $b$, and I have $c$. I need to find $A$, such that $Ab = c$. In this particular case, $A$ is a rotation matrix, yes. May you please expand your comment into an answer, it would be much appreciated! :-)

Comment: @Spacey I did. I hope it's exhaustive enough. Let me know if something was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2D case:**

Let $b=[\beta_1,\beta_2]^T$ and $c=[\gamma_1,\gamma_2]^T$. Obviously, for the existence of a rotation $A$ such that $Ab=c$, we must again have that $\|b\|_2=\|c\|_2$. Let $A$ be of the form $A=\begin{bmatrix}c&-s\\s&c\end{bmatrix}$.
We want $Ab=c$, which is equivalent to
$$
\beta_1 c - \beta_2 s = \gamma_1, \quad \beta_1 s + \beta_2 c = \gamma_2.
$$
Pick your favourite method for solving linear systems (actually, Cramer's rule is pretty neat in this case) and get
$$
c = \frac{\beta_1\gamma_1+\beta_2\gamma_2}{\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2},
\quad
s = \frac{\beta_1\gamma_2-\beta_2\gamma_1}{\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2}.
$$
We should verify that $c^2+s^2=1$:
$$
c^2+s^2=
\frac{(\beta_1\gamma_1 + \beta_2\gamma_2)^2+(\beta_1\gamma_2 - \beta_2\gamma_1)^2}{(\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2)^2}
=
\frac{\beta_1^2\gamma_1^2+\beta_2^2\gamma_2^2+\beta_1^2\gamma_2^2+\beta_2^2\gamma_1^2}{(\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2)^2}
=\frac{(\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2)(\gamma_1^2+\gamma_2^2)}{(\beta_1^2 + \beta_2^2)^2}.
$$
We have $c^2+s^2=1$ provided that $\beta_1^2+\beta_2^2=\gamma_1^2+\gamma_2^2$ which is true since $\|b\|_2=\|c\|_2$ by assumption. Now since we have two numbers $c$ and $s$ such that $c^2+s^2=1$, we can find a $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $c=\cos\theta$ and $s=\sin\theta$.

---

**$n$D case, Householder reflections:**

For larger matrices, the easiest way is probably to use [Householder reflections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).
Again, assume $b$ and $c$ to be nonzero vectors (of the same dimension) such that $\|b\|_2=\|c\|_2$.
A general Householder transformation can be written in the form
$$\tag{HT}
A=I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}.
$$
Applying $A$ on $b$ we get
$$
Ab=\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)b=b-2\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}v.
$$
Since we want $Ab=c$, the equation above implies that we must have $v\in\mathrm{span}\{b,c\}$. Note that it does not matter how we scale $v$ so let $v=b+\alpha c$ for some scalar $\alpha$.
We have
$$\tag{1}
Ab=\left(1-2\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}\right)b-2\alpha\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}c.
$$
We want to get $Ab=c$, so the coefficient by $b$ in (1) must be zero. Using the expression for $v$, this is equivalent to
$$\tag{2}
0=1-2\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}=1-2\frac{b^Tb+\alpha c^Tb}{b^Tb+2\alpha c^Tb+\alpha^2 c^Tc}.
$$
From $\|b\|_2=\|c\|_2$, we have $b^Tb=c^Tc$ so we set in the equation above $b^Tb=c^Tc=\beta$. Then (2) is true iff
$$
0=1-2\frac{\beta+\alpha c^Tb}{(1+\alpha^2)\beta+2\alpha c^Tb} \quad\Leftrightarrow \quad
\alpha^2=1.
$$
Hence we can choose $\alpha$ to be $\pm 1$.
For any such $\alpha$ (we have $v^Tb/v^Tv=1/2$), we obtain
$$
Ab=-2\alpha\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}c=-\alpha c.
$$ 
It follows that with $\alpha=-1$, we get $Ab=c$. Of course, we could also take $\alpha=1$ and multiply the resulting $A$ with $-1$ to get $Ab=c$ again.

> The Householder transformations which map a nonzero $b$ to $c$ (of equal 2-norms) are given by
>   \begin{align}
> A_1&=I-2\frac{v_1v_1^T}{v_1^Tv_1}, & v_1&=b-c, \\
> A_2&=2\frac{v_2v_2^T}{v_2^Tv_2}-I, & v_2&=b+c.
> \end{align}

---

**$n$D case, Givens rotations:**

If you really insist of $A$ being a rotation, what I mean is a product of elementary rotations (similar to the 2D case), you can proceed as follows (maybe there's another way, this is just the simplest approach I can think of now):

- There is a standard procedure which uses [Givens rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) to transform a nonzero vector $b$ to $\rho e_1$, where $\rho=\|b\|_2=\|c\|_2$ and $e_1=[1,0,\ldots,0]^T$. In this procedure, a sequence of Givens rotations $G_2^{(b)},\ldots,G_n^{(b)}$ is constructed such that $G^{(b)}b=\rho e_1$, where $G^{(b)}=G_2^{(b)}\cdots G_n^{(b)}$ is the product of these elementary rotations ($G_n^{(b)}$ annihilates the $n$-th entry of $b$, $G_{n-1}^{(b)}$ annihilates the $(n-1)$-st entry of $G_n^{(b)}b$,..., $G_2^{(b)}$ annihilates the second entry of $G_3^{(b)}\cdots G_n^{(b)}$b).
- Similarly, construct a sequence of elementary Givens rotations such that their product $G^{(c)}$ applied to $c$ makes it equal to $\rho e_1$ (this is OK, since the norms of $b$ and $c$ are equal).
- We have hence that both $G^{(b)}b=\rho e_1$ and $G^{(c)}c=\rho e_1$, so $G^{(b)}b=G^{(c)}c$ and therefore $Ab=c$ with $A=(G^{(c)})^TG^{(b)}$.
  Note that $A$ is a product of elementary rotations so that it is a rotation itself (you can consider it as successively rotating $b$ along the axes of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space).

This approach is somewhat less straightforward and slightly harder to implement (due to the use of the "standard procedure") than the previous one based on Householder reflections which leads to just a simple formula for $A$. Let me know if there'd be something unclear (like, e.g., that "standard procedure") :-)

Comment: Wow thank you! I have to read/digest it, let me get back to you soon! :-)

Comment: I digested your first part, and I solved it via computing 

$$
\begin{bmatrix} c \\ s\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \beta_1 & -\beta_2  \\ \beta_2 & \beta_1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \gamma_1 \\ \gamma_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, we have $\theta = \text{atan2}(\frac{s}{c}) = 134.97 ^{\circ}$, and I think that is correct. So we basically used the symmetry of $A$ in this case, to reformulate this problem into what I wrote above, yes?

Comment: I am now digesting your second part, by the way, thanks again for such a fantastic and thorough answer, I would upvote 100 times if I could! :-)

Comment: I think I have digested your second part @Pavel, I have some questions. 1) I understand the concept of span, but how did you get $v = b + \alpha c$? Shouldn't we use the more general $v = \alpha b + \beta c$? How can we guarantee that we do not have to multiply $b$ by a scalar? 2) For this second exposition you have, this householder transformation method only works if we assume $A$ is a reflection matrix, yes? That is, we cant use this method if $A$ was some arbitrary matrix, correct? I think that is all I have for now. Once again, fantastic job! I learned a lot. :-)

Comment: @Spacey For the first part, yes, you take the coefficients of $A$ as the unknown vector and solve for $c$ and $s$. The second part: 1) Look at the coefficient of $b$, it's $1$ so $b$ has never a zero coefficient in the linear combination. If you take $v=\alpha b+\beta c$, you have always $\alpha\neq 0$. The term $vv^T/v^Tv$ is independent of a scaling of $v$ (you multiply $v$ by whatever nonzero scalar and you still get the same thing). So for that reason, you can fix the coefficient by $b$ as you like (e.g., 1)....

Comment: @Spacey 2) Yes, Householder transformations are always reflections. If you want to use rotations, you could use the second approach with elementary rotations.

Comment: Pavel, I understand all except for the part about the scaling. Ok, the starting point I have is $b - 2\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}v = c$. Furthermore, we know that $v$ is in $\text{span}(b,c)$. So far so good. However I am perplexed by how exactly we conclude that $v = b + \alpha c$. To me span means any linear combination of $b$ and $c$. Even if the scaling does not matter... I just dont get this...

Comment: @Spacey You can of course set $v=\alpha b + \beta c$, where we know that $\alpha$ is nonzero. The point is that if you set $\tilde{v}=\frac{1}{\alpha}v=b+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}c=b+\tilde{\alpha}c$, then $\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}=\frac{\tilde{v}\tilde{v}^T}{\tilde{v}^T\tilde{v}}$ and hence $\frac{v^Tb}{v^Tv}v=\frac{\tilde{v}^Tb}{\tilde{v}^T\tilde{v}}\tilde{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

If ${\bf b}$ is rotated to ${\bf c}$ in ${\Bbb R}^3$ then the axis of rotation will be in the direction of ${\bf a}={\bf b}\times{\bf c}$, so now all we have to do is find the angle.  This can be done by applying the dot product formula to ${\bf b}$ and ${\bf c}$.

Now choose an orthonormal basis for ${\Bbb R}^3$ including the unit vectors $\hat{\bf a}$ and $\hat{\bf b}$.  The matrix of the rotation with respect to this basis will be
$$R=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr 0&\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\cr 0&\sin\theta&\cos\theta\cr}\ ,$$
and this can be converted by the usual procedure to a matrix with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: David thank you but I have no idea how to implement your idea... how can this be applied to my specific problem? I'm given the point before the transformation, and the point after the transformation. I can solve this geometrically. But how do I exactly solve it albegraicly, using linear algebra methods? Thanks

Comment: You are given ${\bf b}$ and ${\bf c}$ so everything I suggested can be calculated.  As for methods... using cross product, dot product, choosing bases etc... I would certainly call those linear algebra methods.  Maybe I didn't understand your quesion correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve a system of equations is to reduce the matrix to triangular. Well, take a triangular $A$. That gives you a system of equations that is easy to solve row by row.